# Inkscape: Collapse borders between consecutive boxes

Tags: inkscape

I need to make several diagrams with many precisely-size, consecutive, bordered boxes. I'm snapping all the edges of my boxes, but box strokes are inlaid; it looks like snapping the edge to the grid determines the maximum extent of the box. The side-effect is that when I put boxes next to one another on the grid borders appear doubled.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

What's the best work-around for this? I've come up with a few ways to cope, but most of them involve making bizarre sized boxes that are hard to color fill.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the problem is here. Are you trying to make the borders look like the ones between "Hdr" and "A", or the one between "A" and the blank box? If the latter, have you tried using the node tool to drag the handles to the grid?

Comment: I want the border between Hdr and A to be the width that the right side of A is. Dragging the handles to the grid doesn't solve it because the border is inset on the shape then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way Inkscape snaps stroked objects to grid has always felt a little inconsistent to me.  Perhaps there is a logic to it, but I'm just not getting it.

Anyway, a simple workaround is to temporarily remove the stroke from your boxes, e.g. by setting their stroke color to "none", and then dragging their corners so that they lie on grid points:

[image: Image 1]

Then just add back the strokes:

[image: Image 2]

Comment: A pain, but exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you can:

1. Overlap the boxes so that the edges are overlapping and are therefore "merged"
2. Draw custom boxes, e.g. draw an outer box with lines in between or smaller boxes with 3-sides
3. Related to #2 - draw a box for the colour, and a box for the stroke. The box for the colour will have no stroke, and the box for the outline has no fill.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply disabling the grid?  When I snap two boxes together in Inkscape, it appears as a single line.